# Kafka S3 Sink Connector - how to mark a partition as complete

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, batch-processing, hadoop-partitioning, system-design

I am using Kafka sink connector to write data from Kafka to s3. The output data is partitioned into hourly buckets - `year=yyyy/month=MM/day=dd/hour=hh`. This data is used by a batch job downstream. So, before starting the downstream job, I need to be sure that no additional data will arrive in a given partition once the processing for that partition has started.

What is the best way to design this? How can I mark a partition as complete? i.e. no additional data will be written to it once marked as complete.

**EDIT:** I am using RecordField as timestamp.extractor. My kafka messages are guaranteed to be sorted within partitions by the partition field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on which Timestamp Extractor you are using in the Sink config.

You would have to guarantee the no records can have a timestamp earlier than the time you consume it.

AFAIK, the only way that's possible is using the WallClock Timestamp Extractor. Otherwise, you are consuming a Kafka Record timestamp, or some timestamp within each message. Both of which can be overwritten on the Producer end to some event in the past

Comment: I am using `RecordField` as `timestamp.extractor`. My kafka messages are guaranteed to be sorted by this field within kafka partitions btw.

Comment: How are you guaranteed that? If someone tomorrow sets that field in their records as -1 timestamp, then that'll be a problem, right? If you have full control over what timestamps are produced, then, sure, there's no issue with the partitioning other than dealing with consumer lag

Comment: THe kafka messages correspond to CDC data from postgres. So, the source timestamp is strictly increasing. So data comes in pre-sorted fashion. I'm then using this field to create partitions.

Comment: Makes sense. Still, there is no semantics for "completion" of an S3 prefix in the connector since it has no context of where data originates

Comment: So, the only option is to have a custom job that reads, maybe, 1 message from each kafka partition and checks for completion across partitions?

Comment: I guess that'll work, assuming the cluster is up and healthy... We also have a similar process processing S3 data, and I think the data analysts just assume data will be there. Other people got fancy with checking the timestamp of the offset of the most recently written file (its in the filename)

Comment: Thanks for the real world insight on your systems